# How do you make height of context menu items not be fixed (ie scale to size of the particular item) in .Net?

Tags: .net, winforms, contextmenu, menuitem

See the two images below.  I don't want each item in the menu to be the height of the largest.  It should size to fit the contents.  I've played around with a number of properties and haven't been able to prevent this behavior.  Is it possible?

[image: Desired Height]
<sub>(source: [blakerobertson.com](http://www.blakerobertson.com/storage/perm/contextNormal.png))</sub>

[image: Fixed Height For all!]
<sub>(source: [blakerobertson.com](http://www.blakerobertson.com/storage/perm/contextThick.png))</sub>

Comment: I personally wouldn't be showing an exception in the context menu. I would check for the exception on load, provide a small error message an icon, then show a dialog if the context menu item is clicked

Comment: @johnc +1 That's the approach i'm going to take if there is no easy solution.  I was going to cleanup the error message considerably that's for sure :P

Answer (score 2):

Set [MenuItem.OwnerDraw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.ownerdraw.aspx) to true, then handle the [MenuItem.MeasureItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.measureitem.aspx) event.  This allows you to tell Windows Forms the size of this menu item independently of the size of others, albeit at the cost of having to then render the item yourself.

Note this does *not* result in automatic size-to-fit: you will need to use GDI+ functions to calculate the desired size.

Comment: In my case... wouldn't i then need to handle the MenuItem.MeasureItem event for all the contenxt menu items EXCEPT for the top one (the big one)?

Comment: I believe that menu items that are not owner-draw would get the default menu item size.  By leaving the "Windows-managed" text -- i.e. the MenuItem.Text property -- of the owner-draw item empty you would avoid bloating this default size.  (You could still draw whatever text you wanted into the menu item rectangle.)  However, I haven't tested this so you might need to test it!  But if I'm wrong then you can as you say address this by custom-measuring all the menu items -- though this would be rather tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I had the same issue with a `ToolStripMenuItem` shown for a `NotifyIcon`. Solved setting `AutoSize = False`, but it wasn't drawing the text well, I can't understand why. Then I had to draw it by my own handling its Paint event.

```
    Private Sub OneMenuItem_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles OneMenuItem.Paint
        If Me.DesignMode Then Return
        Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
        Dim it = OneMenuItem
        Dim p = it.GetCurrentParent
        Using b As New Drawing.SolidBrush(it.ForeColor)
            g.DrawString(it.Text, it.Font, b, p.Padding.Left + 4 + it.Padding.Left, p.Padding.Top + 4 + it.Padding.Top)
        End Using
    End Sub
```

don't ask me what are those magic 4, they worked well comparing both drawn texts in DesignMode (it draws the text ok in design mode and you can compare).
VS2008, btw.