# Icon size in the menu, vb.net application

Tags: vb.net

I have set Icons for the menu in my vb.net application but the icon size is too small.
How to make it look bigger?
Thanks
Furqan

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143757/how-do-you-make-height-of-context-menu-items-not-be-fixed-ie-scale-to-size-of-t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should Use ImageScaling Property of menustripItem